# Elementor Custom Query to get Posts by ACF (Post Object Field

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields

I have two custom post type **Author** and **Book**. The book cpt have an **ACF Object Field** (*authors_object_field*) that is related to authors. On the author single page i want to display all **books** that have the **author** listed in their **ACF Object Field**. I'm using **Elementor** as page builder. I used this code but dont seems to work. Need your lights :)

```
function my_books_by_author_query($query)
{
    $myCurrentAuthorID = get_the_ID();
    $meta_query = [
        [
            'key' => 'authors_object_field',
            'value' => $myCurrentAuthorID,
            'compare' => '==',
        ]
    ];
    $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
    $query->set('post_type', 'book');
}
add_action('elementor/query/booksByAuthor', 'my_books_by_author_query');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem with this.

```
function my_books_by_author_query( $query ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', 'book' );
    $myCurrentAuthorID = get_the_ID();
    $meta_query = [];
    $meta_query[] = [ 
        'key' => 'authors_object_field',
        'value' => $myCurrentAuthorID, 
        'compare' => 'LIKE', 
    ]; 
    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
}
add_action( 'elementor/query/booksByAuthor','my_books_by_author_query' );
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reference Link:** https://developers.elementor.com/custom-query-filter/#Using_the_Custom_Filter

`arbitrary_name_query_id` - the QUERY ID that you fill in the Elementor field,

the code to be placed within `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/arbitrary_name_query_id', function( $query ) {
    $meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' ); 
    $meta_query[] = [ 
        'key' => 'acf_key', // put ACF relationship field name 
        'value' => get_the_ID(), 
        'compare' => '=', 
    ]; 
    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    $query->set( 'post_type', 'post_type' ); // put post type name 
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, My problem is that I use a ACF Post Object Field instead of a ACF relationship field. and I fail to make a filter based on the ID of this Object